# XCode breakpoint should suspend only current thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, debugging

I need to debug a multithreading bug. So to have the condition that generates the crash I need to stop one thread at a specific point in my code and wait for another thread to reach a second breakpoint.

The problem I have now is that if one thread hits a breakpoint, all other threads are suspended. Is there a way to only stop one thread and let the others run until they hit the second breakpoint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know two ways:
If you run into the first breakpoint you should see the debug navigator on the left side of xcode with a list of currently running threads. The thread you are currently on should be expanded. Right click on this thread and select 'suspend thread'. This is it.

If you later want to continue it, you can just click on resume.
(In order to see the threads the execution has to be pause so you either have to be in a break point to do this or pause the app yourself! )

Other more fun option:

When you hit the first breakpoint, you could go into console and write

```
po [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3600]
```

that should pause the thread in the current context at that breakpoint for one hour.

Then resume the execution in Xcode.

Comment: Btw. suspending special threads may result in unexpected pauses: The main thread is used by some Apple internal methods and also the webthread is used by all socket connections you do!

Comment: +1 I think this might work (however, I cannot say I've actually tried it).  Your comment is something of an understatement, however; suspending the main thread will pretty much shut down the user interface of an app entirely.

Comment: Yes ^^ But I mainly wanted to point out that other less obvious system function may also not work! The main thread is used by some methods to channel execution and at least in an early version of iOS the nonatomic properties did rely on the main thread. I think this is not the case anymore though